# Как изменить цвет фона (подложки) у MDLabel (Label) приложения kivy

Tags: python, kivy, design, background-color, kivymd

Пытаюсь поменять цвет фона MDLabel (Label) в kivy. Но не могу сделать так чтобы фон был именно по размеру текста. Т.е. если текста много то фон увеличивается в ширину (на ширину текста), если текста меньше то соответственно фон будет меньше в ширину. Ниже прикрепил картинку для наглядности

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        padding: dp(7)
        # pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        background_color: (1,1,0,1)
        height: self.minimum_height
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            # pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            height: self.minimum_height
            background_color: (0,1,0,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: self.background_color
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Some text'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: self.texture_size
            MDLabel:
                id: trying_to_color_background
                text: 'Width'
                halign: 'right'
                size_hint_x: None
                size: self.texture_size
```

получаю вот это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если убрать последнюю строку "size: self.texture_size". получается вот так, ближе к требуемому результату но все равно не то что нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне надо чтобы фон был прямо по размерам текста (я обвел красным прямоугольником где я бы хотел изменить фон). Если слово будет длиньше, то и фон должен быть шире(по ширине текста), если слово будет короче, то и фон должен быть уже(по ширине текста).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*под словом "текст" я хотел сказать "слово". этот Label будет состоять только из одного слова. слово "width" просто для примера. попытался объяснить максимально. надеюсь поможете. спасибо

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Мне ответили на .com. Данный код работает как надо.

```
...
MDLabel:
    id: trying_to_color_background
    text: 'Width'
    halign: 'right'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    text_size: None, None
```